# How to autorun JS on HTML load

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which is designed to capture keyboard input after the page loads. However, I'm having a problem getting the code to autorun on my website page. I've looked through other documentation and they recommend using:

```
window.onload = function keyboard(e)
```

...this is not working for me. Any help is appreciated.

```
<head>

<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

window.onload = keyboard;

</head>


<script>
// On enter show popup with text entered
var chr = '';
$(document).on('keyup', function keyboard(e) {
  chr += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  console.log(chr);
  $('input:hidden').val(chr);
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    alert(chr);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery included on your page?

Comment: for your window.onload... try just doing `window.onload = keyboard;` and then define your function separately with that same name `function keyboard(e){...}`

Comment: I'm a bit new to jQuery. Is this how you include it? `<head>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
`

Comment: yes, as long as that file exists in the same folder as your web page.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. I added the jQuery to the head and changed the onload as directed.

Comment: can you update the full code in the question - from there I'm sure we can solve this.

Comment: I made the edits to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with jQuery. I must have not been using the right one. Below is the correction which works.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

// On enter show popup with text entered
var chr = '';
$(document).on('keyup', function test(e) {
  chr += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    alert(chr);
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few tricks here. All of the JavaScript code needs to be inside a script tag, and while you could use window.onload if you are using jQuery, you might as well use their .ready() function.

```html
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
//since you have jQuery, you can define your code to run when the page is ready

$(document).ready(function(){
  // On enter show popup with text entered
  var chr = '';
  $(document).on('keyup', function keyboard(e) {
    chr += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    console.log(chr);
    $('input:hidden').val(chr);
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      alert(chr);
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem?

```js
var chr = '';
$(document).on('keyup', function keyboard(e) {
    chr += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    console.log(chr);
    $('input:hidden').val(chr);
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      alert(chr);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```